# TypeError: concat() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate the pandas dataframes in a column-wise manner and reset the index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

com_mut = kirc_mut.loc[common_samples]
com_mut = com_mut.sort_index()
com_mut = com_mut.T
com_mut = com_mut.dropna()
com_mut = com_mut.groupby(com_mut.index).first()

com_mut = com_mut.T
l=[com_mut[x].apply(pd.Series).stack() for x in com_mut.columns]
common_mut=pd.concat(l,1).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 9>()
      7 com_mut = com_mut.T
      8 l=[com_mut[x].apply(pd.Series).stack() for x in com_mut.columns]
----> 9 common_mut=pd.concat(l,1).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
     10 common_mut.columns=com_mut.columns
     12 common_mut

TypeError: concat() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Data:

`common_samples[1:10]`

```
Index(['TCGA-A3-3367-01', 'TCGA-A3-3387-01', 'TCGA-B0-4698-01',
       'TCGA-B0-4710-01', 'TCGA-B0-4810-01', 'TCGA-B0-4811-01',
       'TCGA-B0-4815-01', 'TCGA-B0-4818-01', 'TCGA-B0-4821-01'],
      dtype='object')
```

`kirc_mut.iloc[0:9,0:9]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'A1BG': {'TCGA-A3-3313-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3313-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3317-01': 1,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3331-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3346-01': 0},
 'A1CF': {'TCGA-A3-3313-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3313-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3317-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3331-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3346-01': 0},
 'A2M': {'TCGA-A3-3313-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3313-01A.': 1,
  'TCGA-A3-3317-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01A.': 1,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3331-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3346-01': 0},
 'A2ML1': {'TCGA-A3-3313-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3313-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3317-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3331-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3346-01': 0},
 'A4GNT': {'TCGA-A3-3313-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3313-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3317-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01': 1,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3331-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3346-01': 0},
 'AAAS': {'TCGA-A3-3313-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3313-01A.': 1,
  'TCGA-A3-3317-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3331-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3346-01': 0},
 'AADAC': {'TCGA-A3-3313-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3313-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3317-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3331-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3346-01': 0},
 'AADACL3': {'TCGA-A3-3313-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3313-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3317-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01': 1,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3331-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3346-01': 0},
 'AADACL4': {'TCGA-A3-3313-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3313-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3317-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3319-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01': 1,
  'TCGA-A3-3320-01A.': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3331-01': 0,
  'TCGA-A3-3346-01': 0}})
```

Comment: The error message is clear.  `concat()` only accepts one positional argument, but you used two instead.  Why did you do that?

Comment: You need to pass a sequence (like list) of dataframes to `concat`, all other args are named. You probably wanted `pd.concat(l, axis=1)`.

Comment: @SUTerliakov `l` is the list and `1` is the axis